# How to perform partial refresh of page in APEX5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an APEX page where it contains multiple regions.  Each region has its own drop down list (Select list) item and a bar chart.  My problem is from any particular region when I select a value from the drop down list, the whole page is refreshed as I have the option `Submit page` set for `Page Action on Selection` property.

How do I perform partial refresh so that during the selection from drop down list only the bar chart for that region should be refresh and not the entire page?

Comment: could you please give the steps for this?

Answer (score 1):

Go on your select list item and change the Page Action on Selection property from Submit Page to None. Then create a dynamic action on page with the following options:

- Event=Change
- Selected Type=Items
- Item=Your select list item
- Action=Refresh
- Selection Type=Region
- Region=Your bar chart

Comment: This doesn't work because the value in the select list is not submitted

Answer (score 0):

Same as answer above with one trick to make it work. The value in your select list has not been submitted so will be null and not work.
Add another Dynamic action that runs before the refresh one of type PLSQL. set the code to `null;` then add your select list to the "items to submit".

Should work now :)

Comment: Stop referencing other answers by _above_ or _below_. The order of the answers is not fixed. For me, your answer is the first one so it doesn't make sense when I read _answer above_. Instead, add a link to the answer you're referring to (e.g. _[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098541/5647659)_)